# How to get segfault information for my processes without root permissions?

Tags: dmesg

Debian no longer exposes `dmesg` to users. It contains useful history about crashes. For example:

```
segfault at [...] error 4 in libHSrts_thr-ghc8.0.2.so[7f00f2b6b000+63000]
```

How can I get this information for all of my processes without root permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Run `ulimit -c unlimited`.  This will enable core dumps from segmentation faults which you can use `gdb` and similar debuggers to analyze.